# Role/Group based Authorization using ADAL.js and ASP.NET Web API

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, adal.js

What we are planning to achieve is a role-based security for a Front end Angular-2 and back-end ASP.NET Web API application. We are doing the authentication process with the help of ADAL.js and storing the token in the local storage. We have also implemented the approach shown [here](http://itq.nl/combining-adal-js-with-role-based-security-in-asp-net-web-api/) i.e. to call the Graphi API and get the user groups to stuff them into Claims.

My question is : Is there anyway, we can add role claims from server to the bearerToken which is residing in the local storage. Or is there any better way to approach this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The code sample mentioned assign the role based on the group. If you have the Azure AD basic version, it support to assign the role to the users/groups directly.

> My question is : Is there anyway, we can add role claims from server to the bearerToken which is residing in the local storage. Or is there any better way to approach this issue.

Yes, it is possible. To issue the role claims we need to assign the users to assign the roles to users or group first. Then when the user acquire the token, the Azure AD would issue the relative role claims in the token.

You can refer the code sample for using the role claim from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims).

And you may also be interest in [groups claim developing](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims).

Comment: What we basically want to achieve is map our groups to roles and do role based authorization without going for Azure Active Directory premium.

Is there anyway, we can get the token using ADAL.js and then call Microsoft Graph API on server side and insert groups into the token ?

Comment: No, it is impossible. Because the token is issued/signed from Azure AD. We are not able to change the token for the security consideration.

Answer (score 0):

ok i was struggling with this for a while and i have figured it out i believe.

First,
In Azure AD, set up your WebApi app as application type to be Web App / API.
go to Manifest file and add your roles like

```
[
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User"
      ],
      "displayName": "Reviewer",
      "id": "0238c2bb-9857-4d07-b760-a47ec621d57a",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Reviewer only have the ability to view tasks and their statuses.",
      "value": "reviewer"
    },
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User"
      ],
      "displayName": "Approver",
      "id": "000018cb-19e3-4f89-bf99-5d7acf30773b",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Approvers have the ability to change the status of tasks.",
      "value": "approver"
    }
  ]
```

Then create the the Client app as Application type to be Native app and add required permissions to the service you added above.

In the SPA Angular app add something like this

```
    var endPoints = {
        // "https://localhost:44386/" is the API URL
        // "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" is the Service Application ID
        "https://localhost:44386/": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    };
    adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init({
        instance: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        // tenant is your tenant name (something like below)
        tenant: "{NAME}.onmicrosoft.com",
        // this is the Native app application ID (ClientID) you registered
        clientId: "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
        extraQueryParameter: "nux=1",
        endpoints: endPoints
    }, $httpProvider);
}
```

]);

Then, in your startup.cs you need to set up the Service App like the following:

```
     app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
             new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
             {
                 TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                 {
                /* "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" is the Service Application ID. (Same as you registered in the client app above)*/
                     ValidAudience = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                     RoleClaimType = "roles"
                 },
               /*enant is your tenant name (same as you registered in client app above)*/
                 Tenant = "{NAME}.onmicrosoft.com"
             });
```

Finally you need to go to Azure active directory => Enterprise application => all applications => select your webAPI service => Users and groups => then assign users to the roles.

When this is all done when you log through your client app to authenticate and call the webapi, adal.js and ada-angular.js will put the proper bearer token that contains roles

Answer (score 0):

Good to learn this approach.

Ted, thanks for sharing your solution !

For those who are not familiar with operating Azure AD manifest file. The following is a good resource. 
https://thinkthencode.wordpress.com/2016/04/24/azure-ad-using-app-roles-for-authorization/

```
"appRoles": [
        {
  "allowedMemberTypes": [
    "User"
  ],
  "displayName": "Reviewer",
  "id": "0238c2bb-9857-4d07-b760-a47ec621d57a",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "description": "Reviewer only have the ability to view tasks and their statuses.",
  "value": "reviewer"
},
{
  "allowedMemberTypes": [
    "User"
  ],
  "displayName": "Approver",
  "id": "000018cb-19e3-4f89-bf99-5d7acf30773b",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "description": "Approvers have the ability to change the status of tasks.",
  "value": "approver"
}
    ]
```